# Why ĭdem instead of iddem or īdem in neuter?

Tags: language-evolution, pronouns, morphology

The pronoun *idem/eadem/idem* appears to be the combination of *is/ea/id* and *-dem*.
I can understand why *isdem > īdem* in the masculine, but why do we have *iddem > ĭdem*?
Shouldn't the vowel be longer to compensate for the lost consonant?
The first syllable in *ĭdem* is short (or light).
Is the shortness there just to disambiguate it from the masculine?
Such ambiguity would be easy to live with, so I expect the reason to be different.
Or is *idem* perhaps pronounced as if it was *iddem* but still spelled with a single D?
Otherwise the pronoun behaves as expected, but the neuter singular nominative and accusative strikes me as odd.
I don't know much about length compensation, so I am certainly missing something here.

Comment: Loss of a coda consonant doesn't always result in compensatory lengthening; in fact I believe (though don't have a reference) that this is less common with plosives like *d* than with continuants.

Comment: Because iddem > ĭdem is incorrect. According to one hypothesis,  n. ĭdem, with the enclitic -em,  was reanalyzed as *iddem and that gave rise to a new enclitic -dem; hence, e.g. m. isdem > īdem.

Comment: Either of the comments would make a fine answer.